# mouseover some div and show another div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want when mouseover on (li.title) , then show next (div.content) with jquery.
i tested some codes but when mouseover title, then just show one content.

now what can i do?

my Html Codes

```
<div class="posts">

<li class="title">
<a href="#">Title post</a>
</li>

<div class="content">
Content
</div>

</div>

<div class="posts">

<li class="title">
<a href="#">Title post</a>
</li>

<div class="content">
Content
</div>

</div>

<div class="posts">

<li class="title">
<a href="#">Title post</a>
</li>

<div class="content">
Content
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `display` to hide the elements then With Jquery you can do this:

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
  $(this).next('.content').toggle();
})
```

Check this <kbd>[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwgujjb5/)</kbd>

Also just with CSS you can show the element with this:

```
.title:hover + .content {
   display:block;
}
```

Check this <kbd>[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwgujjb5/1/)</kbd>

**But take in care because you can't use `li` elements outside an `ul` your code is invalid change the `li` to `div`**

Answer (score 0):

rename your content as content1, content2, content3 to see the different body and the code :

```
$('.title').mouseover(function () {

    alert($(this).next('div').html());
});
```

then you can hide all content and show up the right next content

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/77wc17yo/

```
$('.posts').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.content').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML/DOM structure is incorrect, "li" tag must be direct child of "ul" or "ol", and cant have siblings other than "li". Incorrect DOM structure can lead to many issue like this.

Fix your DOM structure to be like this

```
<div class="posts">

<h4 class="title">
<a href="#">Title post</a>
</h4>

<div class="content">
Content
</div>

</div>
```

then use the following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.title').on('hover',function(){
     $(this).next('.content').css({border: red solid 2px, display: block});
  });
});
```